# Yet another word guessing puzzle

Tags: word

If I slice it, it looks tasty.
If I play with it, my hands becomes dirty.
If I leave a mark on it, it becomes red and red.
If I put it on a certain animal, it runs very fast and becomes quite dangerous!

What is the word I am thinking of?

Comment: The answer is tape right? My cat goes totally berserk if I put tape on her back o.o

Comment: This is a pure word puzzle :)

Comment: I'm a little new to puzzling, what do you mean by a "pure" word puzzle?
@user3664611

Comment: It seems to me that**any* fruit in red color fits as an answer

Comment: @DavidFoong The only thing involved in the puzzle is the word's property itself, and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

> **Shrubbery**

If I slice it, it looks tasty.

> *bery* looks like *berry*

If I play with it, my hands becomes dirty.

> If you play with the word (rearrange and swap letters), it's somewhat similar to *grubby*, or *rubbish*, which are dirty. Alternatively, it contains the letters for *brush*, which could get paint on your hands. Perhaps *robbery*, for a metaphorical *dirty hands*. Or literally, playing with bushes will get your hands dirty!

If I leave a mark on it, it becomes red and red.

> Not sure! A *bush* could *blush*? Also, *<strike>sh</strike>rub<strike>ber</strike>y* leaves *ruby*.

If I put it on a certain animal, it runs very fast and becomes quite dangerous!

> If you add *hedge* (a shrubbery) to a *hog*, it becomes a hedgehog! Sonic runs fast, and hedgehogs are spiky (dangerous).

Comment: "Shrubbery + hog = hedgehog" is possibly my new favorite equation.  Thank you for that chuckle :)

Comment: It's not the answer. It's also very complicated and quite kludgy :P

Answer (score 0):

If I slice it, it looks tasty.

> Tomato looks tasty after slicing it

If I play with it, my hands becomes dirty.

> La Tomatina is played with tomatoes (in Spain) and people playing it become dirty

If I leave a mark on it, it becomes red and red.

> If you put a red mark on tomato, it is red and red

If I put it on a certain animal, it runs very fast and becomes quite dangerous!

> If you put it in front of a bull's eyes, the bull becomes angry and runs fast

What is the word I am thinking of?

> You are thinking of a TOMATO

Comment: Sorry, but it's not correct. Anyways, this is a pure word puzzle, so I think you're in the wrong track :)